# TypeError when running Pythonshell on my Mac

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, macos, typeerror

I run a python script in node.js using python shell.
On my Windows system everything runs fine.
But running the same thing on my Macbook get's me this error:

```
Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
    at PythonShell.parseError (/Users/johannes/Dropbox/Javascript Projects/DNA Assembler/Algorithmus_Visualisierung/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:183:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/johannes/Dropbox/Javascript Projects/DNA Assembler/Algorithmus_Visualisierung/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/johannes/Dropbox/Javascript Projects/DNA Assembler/Algorithmus_Visualisierung/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:88:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "Assembler.py", line 224, in <module>
      reads, n, nUnique, nComplements = readReads(path, verbose = True)
    File "Assembler.py", line 20, in readReads
      reads = random.sample(reads, round(len(reads) * subset))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 326, in sample
      result = [None] * k
```

Does someone have an idea what might be going wrong here?
I'm looking for a solution, that does not involve changing a lot in my .py because everything runs fine in Windows.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what is wrong with a script if you didn't show us any of the code? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks like you've passed a float instead of an integer as the list length to `random.sample`, probably due to improper division syntax. But we can't give more specific help without some code, preferably a MCVE, as previously suggested by Cory.

Comment: @PM2Ring you were right, I had to change one 1.0 to 0.
I didn't post code initially because I have quite a lot of code and I wan't even sure if it was due to code, since I only had this problem on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing a float value to int.

(though it would be interesting to know, why this only occurred on Mac.)